# NumberFormatException ArrayList size Javabean method in JSP with JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl, javabeans, numberformatexception

Im a little new to JSTL and Javabeans so I'm having a lot of trouble figuring this one out.

I have an index.jsp, a class called CustomerScheme which extends an ArrayList, and a test.jsp which im using for output.

index.jsp contains the following code, and has a link to test.jsp:

```
<jsp:useBean id="scheme" scope="session" class="customer.beans.CustomerScheme">

    <%
        // Open a stream to the init file
        InputStream stream =
                application.getResourceAsStream("/fm.txt");

        // Get a reference to the scheme bean
        CustomerScheme custScheme =
                (CustomerScheme) pageContext.findAttribute("scheme");

        // Load colors from stream
        try {
            custScheme.load(stream);
        } catch (IOException iox) {
            throw new JspException(iox);
        }
    %>

</jsp:useBean>
```

test.jsp contains:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
${scheme.size}
```

CustomerScheme extends ArrayList, and has the method:

```
public int getSize() {
    return this.size();
}
```

CustomerScheme has more code. I'll post it if you need.

**My problem is this**: Whenever I run the program, I start at index.jsp, click the link to go to test.jsp, and then get the following:

[image: Error Message]

Comment: `EL` treats an object as a `map` (coercion factor) cannot resolve `size` field. So you need to call the `getSize()` method - ${scheme.getSize()} Or use `<jsp:getProperty />`

Comment: Hmm, ok that works. For some reason I was led to think that you could access attributes like this: ${guy.name.firstName}, if guy has a function getName(), and the name has a function getFirstName(). Is there anything similar to this that I may be confusing this with? -- btw your comment fixed my issue, I will give you correct answer if you submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `javax.el.ListELResolver` handles base objects of type `java.util.List`. It accepts any object as a property and *coerces* that object into an integer index into the list.

So you need to call the `getSize()` method - `${scheme.getSize()}` or use `<jsp:getProperty/>`

Alternatively, you can create a `List<T>` in `customer.beans.CustomerScheme` instead of extending `ArrayList<T>`.

```
public class CustomerScheme{
  private List<Customer> list=new ArrayList<Customer>();
  public int getSize(){
         return list.size();
  }
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create an extra wrapper class you can do the following:

```
<c:set var="size"><jsp:getProperty name="scheme" property="size"/></c:set>
size : <c:out value="${size}"/>
```